# Type error in Haskell when pattern matching against Maybe with Show constraint

Tags: haskell, types, pattern-matching

```
import Data.Maybe

f :: (Show t) => Maybe t -> IO () 
f Nothing  = putStrLn   "Nothing!"
f (Just x) = putStrLn $ "The number is " ++ (show x)

main = do
  f Nothing
```

This gives:

```
foo.hs:7:3:
    No instance for (Show a0) arising from a use of ‘f’
    The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Show a => Show (Maybe a) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
      instance Show Ordering -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
      instance Show Integer -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
      ...plus 22 others
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: f Nothing
    In the expression: do { f Nothing }
    In an equation for ‘main’: main = do { f Nothing }

foo.hs:7:3:
    No instance for (Show a0) arising from a use of ‘f’
    The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Show a => Show (Maybe a) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
      instance Show Ordering -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
      instance Show Integer -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
      ...plus 22 others
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: f Nothing
    In the expression: do { f Nothing }
    In an equation for ‘main’: main = do { f Nothing }
```

How can this peace of code be fixed? The point is to safely print a showable. I thought that (Show t) => Maybe t could be destructured into both Nothing and Just x.

Comment: Just to give you a clue why this error exists: compare `show ([] :: [Char])` and `show ([] :: [Int])`. This makes it very clear why e.g. `show []` is ambiguous: should it result in the former value or the latter? Even for "containers" that don't contain any values, one must fix the type of the contained elements before the behavior of `show` is determined.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose you're the compiler, and you're trying to type check your program:

```
main = do
 f Nothing
```

You know that:

1. `main` must have type `IO ()`, because it's a compiler-imposed requirement;
2. `f` must have type `(Show t) => Maybe t -> IO ()`, because that's the type annotation on it.
3. `Nothing` must have type `Maybe a`, where `a = t` (the same `t` as in the use of `f`);
4. Therefore, `a` must be a `Show` instance.

But this isn't enough to get the program to compile, Haskell must **monomorphize** the call to `f` in your `main` action, i.e., figure out the concrete type of every type variable in that particular use of `f`.  In this case, this is because the type of `main :: IO ()` is monomorphic (no type variables in it), so none of the expressions that occur in its definition may have types with uninstantiated type variables.

So that's what this ambiguous type error means: your program doesn't have enough information for the compiler to figure out the element type of the `Maybe` argument to your call to `f`.  All it can figure out is that it must be a `Show` instance, but that's not enough get the program to compile.

The solution is to add a type annotation somewhere that picks a concrete type for it.  There are many ways:

```
main = f (Nothing :: Maybe Int)

main = f argument
  where argument :: Maybe Integer
        argument = Nothing

main = (f :: Maybe String -> IO ()) Nothing
```

The reason there isn't just one way is that type inference is like a detective—it works by putting together a lot of different clues, and thus there are many different hints you can give it that will allow it to "solve the case."

Comment: `main` can have any `IO` type, not just `IO ()`, although that's not too relevant here.

Comment: @dfeuer: Huh, I didn't know that.  Thanks!

Comment: It's generally clearest, I think, to use `IO ()` for programs that may terminate in an orderly fashion, and to use `IO a` (polymorphic) for programs that only terminate with an uncaught exception, but that's a bit nit-picky.

Answer (score 2):

Here `Nothing` is of any possible `Maybe a` you have to specify which `a` you mean - try

```
main :: IO ()
main = f (Nothing :: Maybe Int)
```

Comment: Should not I type the Nothing as something similar to Maybe Show t?

Comment: I think you can do something like `(Nothing :: forall t. Show t => Maybe t)` but I have not tried and I am almost certain it wont; `f` is polymorphic in its argument but you need a concrete type that `f` works on.

Comment: @RodrigoStv No, function arguments are never (!) polymorphic in Haskell. (Though GHC has extensions to relax this restriction.)